# Deleted files in TMP folder

Tags: filesystem

Today I've downloaded some files and it went into my TMP folder, I doubt it to be a Virus and deleted many files from TMP folder but some of the files didn't get deleted as I don't have sudo privileges.
Can this effects my host operating System functioning?

Answer (score 0):

Won't affect things unless your system starts running out of space, in which case you need to ask for more space from your system admin (the person who can use sudo). Filesystems run dandy with hundred of thousands of files; ext3 has a file number ceiling = (volumesize (in bytes))/(2^13), which is to say, a lot.